# android studio 3.0 canary 5 generate listeners with "1-letter" names for parameters

Tags: android

For example, when I type like

```
list1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
```

it generates
now:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick (AdapterView <?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)
```

was:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick (AdapterView <?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

See- *parent* now *adapterView*,  *position* now *i*, *id* is *l*
And same for other listeners too.
now:

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged (SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b)
```

was:

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged (SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
```

Are they (google android team) drop rules for variable naming? Like - the variable name has to be as descriptive as possible. Don't use generic names.
I hope they will return old names.

Comment: If it's really a thing (double check with old IDE), you could fill a bug report instead of posting here. It will be more beneficial. https://source.android.com/source/report-bugs

Comment: I shouldn't post it. My bad.

Comment: Cant find a way to delete it, or close. Dont want to answer.

Comment: I wouldn't worry much about the post itself. And about the question - maybe there's an option in Android Studio to bring these descriptive parameters back? There's a settings page General -> Code Style -> Java -> Code Generation. Generated parameter names seemed to depend on types and interface parameter's names. Maybe interface parameters were changed?

Comment: Well, I took a look. Many options but nothing that could convert _b_ to _fromUser_ .